# Which algorithm runs faster to count the number of characters in the last word in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a given string, `s`,  I want to calculate the time complexity that it takes to count the number of characters in the last word.

**First Code:**

```
count = 0
flag = 0
for i in s[::-1]:
  if (i == ' '):
     if (flag):
       break
  else:
    count += 1
    flag = 1
```

**Second Code:** //Assuming there is at least 2 words

```
def countLast(sen):
  count = 0
  i = -1
  while abs(i) <= len(sen):
    if sen[i] == " ":
      i -= 1
      continue
    else:
      while sen[i] != " ":
        count += 1
        i -= 1
      return count
```

The first code will run in `O(n) + O(w)` where `n` is the number of words in the string, since I am using `[::-1]` in the for loop, and `w` is the number of characters in the last word.

My argument is that the second code snippet will run in `O(w)`, where `w` is the number of characters.

Is this correct? and which algorithm will take less time complexity (which will run faster)?

Comment: a) I doubt if performance is that important, and b) `for i in range(len(s)-1, -1, -1):` avoids reversing the string, although there are too many `-1`s there for my liking.

Comment: Just saying, `len(s.rpartition(' ')[-1])` is by far faster than both of your functions.

Answer (score 0):

I first made a function of your first code, like this:

```
def first(s):
    count = 0
    flag = 0
    x = 0
    for i in s[::-1]:
        if (i == ' '):
            if (flag):
                break
        else:
            x += 1
            flag = 1
```

Then, in iPython I just used the function `%timeit` Here is the result

```
In [31]: strings
Out[31]: ['a a', 'a aa', 'a aaa', 'a aaaa', 'a aaaaa', 'a aaaaaa']
In [32]: for s in strings:
    ...:     print("for the first function --> ")
    ...:     %timeit first(s)
    ...:     print("count last function -->" )
    ...:     %timeit countLast(s)
for the first function -->
272 ns ± 2.27 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
count last function -->
310 ns ± 3.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
for the first function -->
331 ns ± 13.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
count last function -->
437 ns ± 45.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
for the first function -->
380 ns ± 8.15 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
count last function -->
456 ns ± 2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
for the first function -->
434 ns ± 6.32 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
count last function -->
540 ns ± 5.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
for the first function -->
496 ns ± 13.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
count last function -->
649 ns ± 15 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
for the first function -->
542 ns ± 11.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
count last function -->
751 ns ± 30.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

So, the first function *appears* to be faster

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I believe that is because the input string you used is too small. Therefore, `[::-1]` is not really taking time to reverse the array in the first code. Try to use at least 10 lines or more than 50 words, then see how it goes!